# Accessing non-static methods containing variables from the class inside the main method?

Tags: java, variables, methods, static

I'm learning java and was trying to create a simple program to help me find a way (if there is one) to access non-static methods inside the main method of the same class. This is what I have so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodVariables

{

    public int num1;
    public int num2;
    public int add = (num1 + num2);
    public int sub = (num1 - num2);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the first number: ");
        String num1 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the second number: ");
        String num2 = input.nextLine();
        input.close();

        // I know these wouldn't work this way but this is just to show what I am trying to accomplish
        addition(add);    
        subtraction(sub);
    }

    public void addition(int add)
    {
        System.out.println("The sum of the two is: " +add);
    }

    public void subtraction(int sub)
    {
        System.out.println("The diference of the two is: "+sub);
    }
}
```

If anyone knows what I am overlooking I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: Make the addition() and subtraction() methods static as well. You cannot access instance data from a static context in Java. Alternative: create an instance of MethodVariables in main() and use that instance to get at addition() and subtraction() members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just create an instance of the class in `main`:

```
MethodVariables instance = new MethodVariables();

instance.addition(num1);
instance.subtraction(num2);
```

Since `addition` and `subtraction` are *instance methods*, then you'll always need an instance of the class to call them on.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to the original question, but is worth pointing out:

```
public int add = (num1 + num2);
```

This will not work as you expect.  If you want a function that adds two numbers, just make a function that adds two numbers.

```
public int add(int num1, int num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}

public int subtract(int num1, int num2) {
    return num1 - num2;
}
```